# SQL include AND exclude query

Tags: sql

I have table *t* that contains a person's name and the products they have:

```
NAME    PRODUCT
Adam    a
Adam    b
Adam    c
Ben     c
Ben     d
Chris   b
Dave    a
Dave    b
Dave    c
Dave    d
Evan    a
Evan    b
Fred    a
```

And I want a SQL query that returns NAME when the person has Product a or b or both, AND does NOT have either product c nor d (nor e, f, ...):

```
NAME
Chris
Evan
Fred
```

The actual 'does NOT have' list I'm working with is long, so I would like to avoid having to type in every single product name to exclude, if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "`The actual 'does NOT have' list ... is long`". Can you describe just this list via an sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM T
WHERE product IN ('a', 'b')
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM T WHERE product IN ('c', 'd', 'e', 'f'))
```

Or, if you have all those unwanted c d e f products in another table T2,

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM T
WHERE product IN ('a', 'b')
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM T
                 WHERE product IN (SELECT product FROM T2))
```

Or, if the unwanted products are actually all except a and b:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM T
WHERE product IN ('a', 'b')
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM T
                 WHERE product NOT IN ('a', 'b'))
```

Comment: Thanks. This will work if I name every product to exclude (the real product list is quite long). Is there a way to tell it to exclude all but 'a' and 'b' in the NOT IN statement?

Comment: Great! Your third example is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I know in T-SQL (MSSQL) you can use `EXCEPT` to exclude results:

```
SELECT Name FROM t WHERE Product IN ('a','b')
EXCEPT
SELECT Name FROM t WHERE Product NOT IN ('a','b')
```

`EXCEPT` also only returns `DISTINCT` results.
See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8835a/2).

The second `SELECT` query after the `EXCEPT` doesn't have to have the Products to exclude hard-coded and can retrieve them from another table or however else you wish.

Comment: Updated to exclude everything that isn't A or B as per comment on another answer.

Comment: I like this solution. Very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name
from   t
where  exists
       (select * from t as t2
        where  t.Name = t2.Name 
               and Product in ('a','b'))
       not exists
       (select * from t as t2
        where  t.Name = t2.Name 
               and Product not in ('a','b'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a "set-within-sets" query.  I think the most flexible approach is aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select name
from table t
group by name
having sum(case when product in ('a', 'b') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product in ('c', 'd') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

The first condition of the `having` clause counts the number of rows with `'a'` or `'b'`.  A "name" passes when there is at least one row.  The second condition filters out products that you don't want.

If you only wanted `'a'` or `'b'` and nothing else, the condition would be:

```
having sum(case when product in ('a', 'b') then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when product not in ('a', 'b') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: I am saving this, as it will likely be very useful for me in future queries. Thanks for the detailed explanation!